# CSS wrapper isn't growing with floated children

Tags: css

I have a wrapper on my page that is styled by this rule

```
#wrapper{
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #FFF;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Problem is, the wrapper doesn't grow if the children are floated. After a little Googling i found that adding display:none would solve it. And it did, but i can't do that since some of my element HAVE to overflow the wrapper (design elements that are sticking out through the wrapper).
How can i solve it without using overflow:hidden?

Comment: clear:both under floating divs?

Comment: have you clear you floated elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to clear your floated elements e.g.

```
<div style="float:left"></div>
<div style="float:right"></div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
```

Comment: I have i page with two floated divs. On the left one i set clear: left, and on the right one clear:right. Made no difference :(

Comment: Oh sorry, now i understand what you mean. Worked great :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a common issue when working with floats. There are a couple of common solutions:

1. Add a div after the floats with `clear: both`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/).

   ```
   <div style="float: left"></div>
   <div style="float: left"></div>
   <div style="clear: both"></div>
   ```
2. Add the two floats into a container with the CSS attribute `overflow: auto`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/1/).

   ```
   <div style="overflow: auto">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
3. Make the parent element a float. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/2/).

   ```
   <div style="float: left">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```
4. Use the :after CSS pseudo element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/3/).

   ```
   .parentelement:after {
       content: ".";
       display: block;
       height: 0; 
       clear: both; 
       visibility: hidden;
   }
   ```
5. Adding a set height to the parent element. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/dX2Xh/4/).

   ```
   <div style="height: 200px">
       <div style="float: left"></div>
       <div style="float: left"></div>
   </div>
   ```

Personally, I use option 2 for simplicity and semantics' sake